# In TFS Can I Assign Work Items based on a State?

Tags: azure-devops, tfs-2015

I'm using TFS 2015 and our team has one tester.  Is there any way configure a default  change to the `Assigned To` field to our tester based on a `State` change from *Active* to *Resolved* the same way the `Reason` field does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be achieved.

1. First, you need to change the related work item type. (Need 
   [TFS PowerTools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1) installed)
2. Then you just need to add the filed `System.AssignTo` during the
   transition.
3. Add rules **copy** , From **Value**, Value="*Your tester Name*".

[image]

More details please refer the tutorial form MSDN：[Update a Field during a workflow changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194981.aspx#Update%20a%20field%20during%20a%20workflow%20change)

---

**Update**

How to open the work itme type, after install the TFPT, you just need to open ***Tools-Process Editor-Work item Types-Open WIT from Server*** in VS, then just select the work item type you need to customize.

[image]

Comment: How do I find the workflow template to edit it?  I have TFSPT2015 installed, but finding the template isn't intuitive.

Comment: After install the TFPT, you just need to open ***Tools-Process Editor-Work item Types-Open WIT from Server*** in VS, details please see my update.